# Get value from HTML TD Between Div

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the value between the div, as I am trying to continue the program once the code has been introduced correctly. However I can't seem to get the value from the element.
Value is in this case '12345678'

```
<td id="TransaccionTesoreriaRetencionItems_NroComprobanteRetencion_1" height="22px">
    <div style="width: 115px; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;">
        12345678&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</td>
```

[Code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOYJI.png)

Comment: use ``` for code blocks :)

Answer (score 1):

To print the text ***12345678*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td#TransaccionTesoreriaRetencionItems_NroComprobanteRetencion_1 > div").text)
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@id='TransaccionTesoreriaRetencionItems_NroComprobanteRetencion_1']/div").text)
  ```